# What does なのね at the end of a sentence mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, sentence-final-particles, anime

A certain character in an anime series I watch would literally end each sentence with なのね. What does this imply? He was a pretty flamboyant character who was supposed to be Italian, if that offers any additional insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

なのね lends the same emphasis to a sentence as なんですね. However, なのね is more conversational, informal and can come across as feminine.

According to my teacher, people who end all their sentences with this kind of emphasis in real life can come across as self-important, presumably because it sounds like they're attaching added importance to everything they say.

That may be a factor here, and it certainly matches with the flamboyance of the character.

Comment: In FFXIII-2, there is a Chocobo-girl (Casino shop assistant in Serendipity) that always ends her sentence in なのです. I have no idea what additional connotations there are.

Comment: @ジョン Seems self-important because it's both emphatic and an appeal for assent, like a more authoritative "I know, right?"

Answer (score 1):

**The な：**

I have my own hypothesis about this な and it is that it is basically a mandatory rewrite of the coupla だ which occurs in certain situations:

- **Adjectives:** We can use the dictionary form of a verb with a noun, for example like this: 食べる人: "the person who is eating;" "the eating person". 食べる+人　→　食べる人. 　This is simple. The verb comes together with the noun. But what if the verb is だ？　きれいだ　+　花　→ きれい_な_花: "the flower which is beautiful". The DA becomes NA.　Hence we have the NA adjectives, which just have a DA in disguise. "Kireida hana" makes logical sense, just like "taberu hito", but the rule is that NA must be used there.
- **Certain relative clauses**:　A clause X can be followed by のに　and followed by another clause Y to express the idea of "even though X, Y".  If X ends in だ, the だ changes to な.　 仕事大変だ　→　仕事大変なのに、楽しいよ: Although my work is hard, it is enjoyable.

So with the above patterns, it is very easy to see how the な in なの comes about: it is　だ changing to な in the presence of の. Like in the previous patterns, other verbs don't change; they just combine with の:　食べるの？ (Will you eat?) But だ changes: 嫌いだ  → 嫌いなの？

**The の**:

The sentence final particle の attached to verbs is used for asking informal questions (「そうなの？」) and making authoritative statements. The exact meaning is elusive, but it has been [hypothesized in a 1987 paper](http://elanguage.net/journals/pip/article/download/151/91) by one Hiroko Minegishi Cook that this の　expresses group authority as opposed to individual authority: it is the speaker's belief that the idea being stated is does not originate with him or her alone, but is backed up somehow by the group that he or she identifies with in that moment: something as narrow as family or as broad as society.

**The ね**:

That is just he familiar ending which seeks agreement: "isn't it?", "don't you agree?", "hmm?"

So those would be the three pieces of なのね.

X-なのね:"It is the case that X, I tell you (with the authority of my group), don't you think so?"

A character who ends most sentences this way would be annoying because doing so means:

- the character is never using polite speech (adding the です copula to make なのですね).
- the character is at times using the group authority の ending inappropriately, even for statements that should be his or her alone.
- the character is always seeking agreement with ね at the end.
- the character has a very repetitive habit which can be annoying regardless of what it is.

Comment: Yes, the 準体助詞「の」 takes the 連体形 before it, and な is the 連体形 of the copula. It is the same nominalizer that has the property to make something a question or emphasize it. (We know it's all the same particle because, when it changes to と in 九州方言, all the relevant uses of の in the standard dialect transfer over to と.)